# Zabbix active check monitoring issue

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I am new to zabbix monitoring tool, and I am facing some issues while configuring active check based monitoring. The Zabbix server is hosted in AWS cloud and the server to be monitored is placed in a datacenter. Some kind of firewall is configured in between these servers. I have installed zabbix-agent on the client-server and added the host in the zabbix UI. When I check the logs, all I could see is the error message
`Get value from agent failed: cannot connect to {server:10050}: interrupted system call.`

Here is what I did so far.
1. installed the zabbix agent in the server.
2. Set the Zabbix server IP in the option "Server"
3. Set StartAgent as 0
4. Set the ServerActive as zabbix server IP
5. Provided the Hostname (Same as the hostname which is running the zabbix agent)
6. Added the agent in the zabbix UI
7. Changed the template for OS and zabbix agent items with zabbix-agent(active)
8. restarted both the client and server services.

Zabbix server and client is installed in RHEL.

When I do a telnet to the server from the client with port 10050/10051, it is able to connect and vice-versa is not happening. The zabbix port is not enabled/allowed on the client side. But for configuring active checks, this is not needed as per many threads which i gone through.
From the client logs, I can see the defined checks are executing, but the UI still shows red.

Thanks for the reply :)
Is there any way to confirm that the active check which configured is correct. I can see the client has picked up the config check list and processing it. Please see the attached logs from the agent log.

```
 23679:20160107:172925.431 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:proc.num[,,run].avg(5m)'
 23679:20160107:172925.431 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:proc.num[].avg(5m)'
 23679:20160107:172925.431 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:system.cpu.load[percpu,avg1].avg(5m)'
 23679:20160107:172925.432 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:system.cpu.util[,iowait].avg(5m)'
 23679:20160107:172925.432 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:system.swap.size[,pfree].last(0)'
 23679:20160107:172925.432 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:vm.memory.size[available].last(0)'
 23679:20160107:172925.432 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:vfs.fs.inode[/,pfree].last(0)'
 23679:20160107:172925.432 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:vfs.fs.inode[/boot,pfree].last(0)'
 23679:20160107:172925.432 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:vfs.fs.inode[/tmp,pfree].last(0)'
 23679:20160107:172925.432 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:vfs.fs.inode[/var,pfree].last(0)'
 23679:20160107:172925.432 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:vfs.fs.inode[/var/tmp,pfree].last(0)'
 23679:20160107:172925.433 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:vfs.fs.inode[/apps,pfree].last(0)'
 23679:20160107:172925.433 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:vfs.fs.size[/,pfree].last(0)'
 23679:20160107:172925.433 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:vfs.fs.size[/boot,pfree].last(0)'
 23679:20160107:172925.433 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:vfs.fs.size[/tmp,pfree].last(0)'
 23679:20160107:172925.433 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:vfs.fs.size[/var,pfree].last(0)'
 23679:20160107:172925.433 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:vfs.fs.size[/var/tmp,pfree].last(0)'
 23679:20160107:172925.433 In evaluate_function() function:'HOSTNAME:vfs.fs.size[/apps,pfree].last(0)'
```

Is there any chances for the existing zabbix server to malfunction if i upgrade it to Zabbix-3.0, and the stable version is available or not?
What kind of steps i should consider to ensure that the active check configured is proper.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of Zabbix agent checks: passive and active. Passive checks are when Zabbix server connects to Zabbix agent. Active checks are when Zabbix agent connects to Zabbix server instead.

The *Get value from agent failed: cannot connect to {server:10050}: interrupted system call.* you have on the red `Z` in Zabbix frontend relates to passive checks. The state of active checks is not reflected in this icon. So if active checks successfully work for you, it is OK.

The fact that the red `Z` does not reset, for instance, if only active checks are used, is a known problem. It has been recently fixed for Zabbix 3.0 under [ZBX-1916](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-1916).

Comment: Thanks, I have modified the question, Can you please take a look.

Comment: There is currently no icon in Zabbix frontend that would show the state of active checks and upgrade to Zabbix 3.0 for the sake of ZBX-1916 will not solve that problem - it will only clear the `Z` state for passive checks if they are not used. One way to ensure that data from active checks is received is to create a nodata() trigger for one of the items, as is done in the default agent templates. (The log you posted seems to be from the server, not the agent.)

Comment: Is it necessary to open a communication port (10051 or 10050) on the client level for the active check to work and send the data to server?

Comment: In order for active checks to work, Zabbix agent should be able to connect to Zabbix server, which is on port 10051 by default. If passive checks are not used, then Zabbix server itself does not connect to Zabbix agent, so opening port 10050 on the agent side is not necessary.